# How to get MD5 from debug.keystore file on mac

Tags: android, xcode4, md5

I want to retrieve my MD5 certificate but I am new to mac, I don't know where the Certificate is stored but I know its in a `.android` folder. My android sdk is in document folder can someone help me to retrieve it please.

> keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore
>   ~/Desktop/release-1.keystore -keystore -storepass android -keypass
>   xxxx!!

Is it correct ?

Comment: where can i find the .android folder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use a Mac or Linux OS, I've discovered that you'll find the **debug.keystore** file at: `~/.android/`.

Comment: i am on a Mac Mountain lion

Comment: Its hidden folder actually.